# Little mistake with Levi-Civita symbol property

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, tensors

I have this equation

$
\varepsilon_{ijk}B_k = \partial_iA_j - \partial_jA_i
$

and I was asked to prove $\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$, where $\mathbf{B}=B^i\mathbf{e}_i$ and $\mathbf{A}=A^i\mathbf{e}_i$, $i=1,2,3$.

Multiplying this equation by $\varepsilon^{ijk}$ and using that $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon^{ijk}=6$ doesn't work and I end up with an additional multiplicative factor of $\frac{1}{3}$. On the other hand, if I multiply the equation by $\varepsilon^{ijl}$ and use $\varepsilon^{ijl}\varepsilon_{ijk}=2\delta^l_k$ instead, I get the right answer.

What is the mistake with my first approach?

Comment: To see the mistake more clearly write out the sums: $\epsilon_{ijk}B_k \equiv \epsilon_{ij1}B_1 + \epsilon_{ij2}B_2 + \epsilon_{ij3}B_3.$ From this it's more clear that multiplying with $\epsilon^{ijk}$ does not make sense (there is no free index $k$ to sum over on the right hand side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't multiply by $\epsilon^{ijk}$ because there's already a $k$ in $B_k$ and indices should not appear more than twice.